# browserfiy-shimでJqueryとHandsontableをbundleしたときに、ブラウザでUncaught Error: Cannot find module 'shims/classes'とエラーが出る

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

Jqueryと[Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/)を使用したjsファイルをbrowserfiyとbrowserify-shimを使ってモジュール化しようとしています。
一応コマンドで`browserify app.js -d -o src/bundle.js`と打ってもエラーは出ないのですが、
ブラウザで確認した時に

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'shims/classes'
```

とエラーが出てしまいテーブルが表示されない状態になります。
どなたか解決方法をご存じの方はいらっしゃいませんか？

OSはOSX Yosemite

ライブラリのバージョン

- browserify: 11.1.0
- browserify-shim: 3.8.10
- jQuery: 2.1.4
- Handsontable: 0.19.0

ソースコードですが

handsontable.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Handsontable</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../handsontable.full.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="example"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var $container;
var data;
require('Handsontable');

data = [['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C'], ['1', '2', '3']];

$container = $('example');
$container.handsontable({
  data: data
});
```

package.jsonのbrowserifyの設定

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
"browser": {
  "Handsontable": "./src/vendor/handsontable.full.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "global:$",
  "Handsontable": { "exports":"Handsontable", "depends": [ "jquery" ] }
}
```

以上よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
対応としては、Handsontableをhtml側から読み込むようにし、package.jsonのbrowserifyの設定を

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:$",
    "handsontable": "global:handsontable"
  }
```

上記のようにすることで動きました。